# How to configure logstash kafka with json deserializer? (Closed)

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration, logstash-file

I have a config in my logstash. Where I need to consume the data from kafka topic and write into to elastic index. This is my conf

```
input {
  kafka{
    codec => json {}
    bootstrap_servers => "my_brokers"
    security_protocol => "SASL_PLAINTEXT"
    sasl_mechanism => "SCRAM-SHA-256"
    sasl_jaas_config => "my security config"
    topics => ["MY_TOPIC"]
    value_deserializer_class => "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.JsonDeserializer"

  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
      hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
      index => "my_index"
  }
}
```

When I run my config, I'm getting this exception.

```
Error: Invalid value org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.JsonDeserializer for configuration value.deserializer: Class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.JsonDeserializer could not be found.
  Exception: Java::OrgApacheKafkaCommonConfig::ConfigException
  Stack: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parseType(org/apache/kafka/common/config/ConfigDef.java:728)
org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parseValue(org/apache/kafka/common/config/ConfigDef.java:474)
org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parse(org/apache/kafka/common/config/ConfigDef.java:467)
```

Did I miss anything in my conf?

Comment: Why do you need to set the `value_deserializer_class `?

Comment: Hi Paulo, I got the issue. In my producer side, the payload is serialized which is from spring package `org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer `. Here in logstash i'm using `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.JsonDeserializer` class which is not part of the apache kafka. Only these deserialization classes are part of apache kafka  [ https://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/Deserializer.html ]

Comment: Understood, but have you test without setting this value ? Could you please remove `value_deserializer_class ` from the config of the input ?

Comment: Yup!, it's working now. In the producer side, I changed the serializer to `StringSerializer`. By default, logstash will use `StringDeserializer`, now I'm able to consume the data and write into elastic index.